# Proof of $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 2$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I calculated with a website that :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 2$$

Is there a proof to this ?

Comment: Are you studying integrals or don't you still know them? Because if you are studying them, this one is quite simple.

Comment: I don't get how you can define $\int_0^\pi \sin(x) dx$ without knowing its result

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to derive this would be via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which I'll state for you:

> If $f(x)$ is a real number for each $a \le x \le b$, and $F$ is a function that has $f$ as its derivative (so $F'(x)=f(x)$ for each $x$). Then:
>   $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

Now, I claim that if $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then $F(x)=-\cos(x)$ satisfies $F'(x)=f(x)$ for each $x$. Is that familiar to you?

Comment: In case of the response "But how do you prove that theorem?", it's quite difficult!

Comment: would be quite easy if we assume f to be continuous.

Comment: @Vim - given the level of the question, I strongly disagree!

Answer (score 2):

If $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x) = -\sin(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ then

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\textrm{d}x = -\cos(x) \,\bigg|^{\pi}_{0} = -(-1)-(-1) = 2$$

This is a pretty basic fact about trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

As we know from chain rule differentiation:

Remember that, if $y = f(u)$ and $u = g(x)$, then $\frac{\partial y}{ \partial x } = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$. In function notation this means that $\frac{\partial y}{ \partial x } = f'(g(x)) . g'(x)$.

And then by using the chain rule in reverse, we have that $\int_{a}^{b} f'(g(x)) . g'(x) = f(g(x))|_{a}^{b} = f(g(b)) - f(g(a)) $.

And in the case of your question, just set $y = f(u) = - cos (u)$ and $u = x = g(x)$. Then we will have $\frac{\partial y}{ \partial x } = sin(x) \times 1 = sin(x)$. And then $\int_{0}^{\pi} sin(x) = -cos(x)|_{0}^{\pi} = -cos(\pi) + cos(0) = 1+ 1 = 2.$

And we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Newton-Leibniz formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Newton-Leibniz_formula):

$\left[ -\cos x \right]_0^{\pi} = -\cos \pi + \cos 0 = 2$